# PostgreSQL оптимальный поиск даты

Tags: sql, postgresql, pandas

Есть SQL таблица в которой хранятся данные по товарам:

| ИМЯ | дата | количество продаж | цена |

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но данные не полные, только за последние 30 дней есть статистика за каждый час в сутках(до этого периода данные в основном только за 1 час, после идет один неполный день(выделенный синим)).

Мне необходимо найти минимальную дату(для каждого товара в таблице) в которой будут данные за 24 часа(на скрине это дата 2023-09-21), и вывести в виде:

```
+-------+-----------------+
| name  | date            |
+-------+-----------------+
|Factu..| 2023-09-21-0-0-0|
+-------+-----------------+
|name...| 2023-08-05-0-0-0|
+-------+-----------------+
|...    | ...             |
```

Вот запрос который показывает нужную дату по выбранному имени. Осталось добавить колонку name.

```
"""SELECT date_trunc('day', date)
FROM table
WHERE name = 'Factu..'
GROUP BY  date_trunc('day', date)
HAVING COUNT(date_trunc('day', date)) = 24
ORDER BY date_trunc('day', date) ASC LIMIT 1;"""
```

Comment: Немного погуглив я пришел к выводу что нужно сделать следующее:   1.Сгруппировать по имени  > 2. Сгруппировать по дате применив COUNT  >  3.  отобразить дату только COUNT(data) = 24  >  4. Применить условие MIN(data)... Помогите составить подобный запрос если я правильно понял.

Comment: *Мне необходимо найти минимальную дату в которой будет 24 часа для того чтобы её подставлять для получения нужного мне диапазона.* Перечитал трижды, но так и не понял, что тут написано...

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035), пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: Внес изменения надеюсь так будет понятнее.

Answer (score 1):

> Мне необходимо найти минимальную дату в которой будут данные за 24 часа

```
SELECT "date"
FROM "table"
GROUP BY "date"
HAVING COUNT("date") = 24
ORDER BY "date" ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Только наверное **date** сначала надо обрезать, оставив дату, убрав время.(на оракловом `trunc(date)`)

Comment: @SwaD Да, точно. Ну ТС сам доработает...

Comment: @Akina. Только у меня в таблице данные по всем товарам. Нужно найденную дату сопоставить конкретному товару.

Comment: @АртемНиколаевич Значит, выполняем пункты 5 и 3 по ссылке, которую я дал в комментарии к вопросу.

Comment: @Akina внес изменения

Comment: @АртемНиколаевич Ну вообще-то предполагалось, что внесённые изменения будут соответствовать прочитанным пунктам. Пункт 5 требует, чтобы были выложены работоспособные скрипты CREATE TABLe + INSERT INTO с примером данных, а пункт 3 - что будет показан требуемый результат для именно этих данных. Ни того, ни другого я как-то не наблюдаю. А по фотографиям (и прочим скриншотам) мы не лечим...